# How do I use a MD5 hash (or other binary data) as a key name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've been trying to use a MD5 hash as a key name on AppEngine, but the code I wrote raises a UnicodeDecodeError

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import hashlib
key = db.Key.from_path('Post', hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())
```

I don't want to use `hexdigest()` as that is not only a kludge, but an inferior one too (base64 would do a better job).

Comment: Can you explain more why you don't think using the hex digest is a good idea?  Seems like a good idea to me..

Comment: I agree w @Peter -- I'm not clear how using the `digest()` is in any way better than `hexdigest()`; the docs warn that it can contain non-ASCII chars including NULL bytes. Seems to me that you're asking for trouble there. Can you explain why `hexdigest()` is an inferior kludge in your situation?

Comment: @Peter, @bgporter: I also agree. What hexdigest does is simply to express the digest as character pairs that signify the hexadecimal digits of the digest. The MD5 digest for `"a"` is `'\x0c\xc1u\xb9\xc0\xf1\xb6\xa81\xc3\x99\xe2iw&a'` while the hexdigest is `'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'`. As you can see, all the characters that are not expressible as ascii (starting with `\x` in the digest) are just converted to two characters in the hexdigest. It's the same thing expressed differently. Plus it's the only way you can specify a key to the AppEngine... I think vz0's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

decode the bytestring with [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
>>> hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest().decode("iso-8859-1")
u"'\xfc\xce\x84h\xa9\x1e\x8a\x12;\xa5\xb1K\xea\xef\xd6"
```

This is basically a "NOP" conversion. It creates a unicode object that is the same length as the initial string and can be converted back to a string just by `.encode("iso-8859-1")` if you wish

Comment: @Noah: It's unclear why you prefer this over hexdigest, since it's roughly 2x more data and is certainly slower to compute.

Comment: @bukzor, The unicode object is exactly the same size as the digest, those are _exacty_ the same bytes as the digest (remember '\xfc' is the repr of a single char etc.) just marked as unicode. The hexdigest is the one that is longer. It _is_ slower than just doing hexdigest, but appengine needs to `.decode()` the str later, so overall it will most likely be slower to use hexdigest.

Comment: You're quite correct. I guess I still don't have a total handle on this unicode stuff. I didn't read closely enough to see the 'u', and the commandline would have told me len=16. I'm adding that to my "answer"

Answer (score 12):

The App Engine [Python docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html) says:

> A key_name is stored as a Unicode
>   string (with str values converted as
>   ASCII text).

The key has to be an unicode-encodeable-string. You need to change the digest() call to hexdigest(), ie:

```
k = hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's think about data sizes. The optimal solution here is 16 bytes:

```
>>> hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest() 
"'\xfc\xce\x84h\xa9\x1e\x8a\x12;\xa5\xb1K\xea\xef\xd6"

>>> len(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())
16
```

The first thing you thought of was hexdigest, but it's not very close to 16 bytes:

```
>>> hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').hexdigest() 
'27fcce8468a91e8a123ba5b14beaefd6'

>>> len(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').hexdigest())
32
```

But this won't give you ascii-encodable bytes, so we have to do something else. The simple thing to do is use the python representation:

```
>>> repr(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())
'"\'\\xfc\\xce\\x84h\\xa9\\x1e\\x8a\\x12;\\xa5\\xb1K\\xea\\xef\\xd6"'

>>> len(repr(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest()))
54
```

We can get rid of a bunch of that by removing the "\x" escapes and the surrounding quotes:

```
>>> repr(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())[1:-1].replace('\\x','')
"'fcce84ha91e8a12;a5b1Keaefd6"

>>> len(repr(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())[1:-1].replace('\\x',''))
28
```

That's pretty good, but base64 does a little better:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())
J/zOhGipHooSO6WxS+rv1g==
>>> len(base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest()))
24
```

Overall, base64 is most space-efficient, but I'd just go with hexdigest as it's likely to be most optimized (time-efficient).

---

Gnibbler's answer gives a length of 16!

```
>>> hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest().decode("iso-8859-1")
u"'\xfc\xce\x84h\xa9\x1e\x8a\x12;\xa5\xb1K\xea\xef\xd6"
>>> len(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest().decode("iso-8859-1"))
16
```

Comment: Not directly an answer, but still potentially relevant information +1

Answer (score 1):

I find using a base64 encoding of the binary data a reasonable solution. Based on your code you could do something like:

```
import hashlib
import base64
print base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest())
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but an obvious thing that could be a problem is that base64 encoding can generate strings that contain both `/` and `+` characters that are likely to trip up URL parsing/escaping/etc.

Answer (score 1):

An entity key in App Engine can have either an ID (a 4 byte integer), or a name (500 byte UTF-8 encoded string).

An MD5 digest is 16 bytes of binary data: too large for an integer, (likely to be) invalid UTF-8. Some form of encoding must be used.

If hexdigest() is too verbose at 32 bytes then try base64 at 24 bytes.

Whatever encoding scheme you use will ultimately be converted to UTF-8 by the datastore, so the following, which at first looks like an optimal encoding...

```
>>> u = hashlib.md5('thecakeisalie').digest().decode("iso-8859-1")
>>> len(u)
16
```

...when encoded into it's final representation is two bytes longer than the base64 encoding:

```
>>> s = u.encode('utf-8')
>>> len(s)
26
```